# verify if largeAddressAware is in effect?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I followed the steps in:

http://lennybacon.com/2010/10/18/UltimateGuideToSpeedUpVisualStudio.aspx

to make my Visual Studio 2010 faster, including the advice toward the bottom labeled "64 bit support" about running `editbin /largeaddressaware deveenv.exe` .  Is there any way I can verify that this command "worked"?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Yes there is, and the necessary tool is included with VS.

Open the "Visual Studio Command Prompt (2010)" console from the start menu, and CD into `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE` (adjust for your own system if you have changed the installation directory or run 64-bit Windows).

Then do:

```
dumpbin /headers devenv.exe | more
```

The start of the output on my machine is:

```
Dump of file devenv.exe

PE signature found

File Type: EXECUTABLE IMAGE

FILE HEADER VALUES
             14C machine (x86)
               4 number of sections
        4BA1FAB3 time date stamp Thu Mar 18 12:04:35 2010
               0 file pointer to symbol table
               0 number of symbols
              E0 size of optional header
             122 characteristics
                   Executable
                   Application can handle large (>2GB) addresses
                   32 bit word machine
```

The second to last line is what you are looking for -- if it's there, your executable is large address aware.

Answer (score 2):

Since I didn't want to install a 1.6 GB heavy add-on to visual studio, I figured an alternative way.

You can upload the .exe onto www.virustotal.com, then under details you can see this near the bottom

`ImageFileCharacteristicsExecutable, Large address aware`

Answer (score 1):

As the article below states, Open Task Manager and verify the the memory in use by the devenv is more than 2 GB.

[Hacking Visual Studio to Use More Than 2Gigabytes of Memory](http://web.archive.org/web/20120220154512/https://stevenharman.net/blog/archive/2008/04/29/hacking-visual-studio-to-use-more-than-2gigabytes-of-memory.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

[VMMap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/vmmap) shows the effect of this, especially useful if your running program isn't necessarily using very much memory yet.

Just select the running process in VMMap and it will show a breakdown of the memory being used. There is an overall summary which includes the total memory used and free memory available, the latter of which is directly affected by the
`largeaddressaware` setting.

For an EXE that I tried this on recently...

Here's the *unmodified* EXE (see the **FREE** line):

[image]

And after turning the flag *on*:

[image]

That seems to confirm that at least its being recognized by Windows.

---

That text is at the roughly middle left in the screenshot from the VMMap site:

> [image]